# Agregar nuevo objeto en mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

estoy tratando de agregar un nuevo objeto `cargo` dentro de `moderable`.

asi lo tengo

**{
"moderable":{
"tipo":1,
"valor":10,
}
}**

Esta es mis sintaxis

`db.piloto.updateMany({},{"$set":{modelable:{cargo:""}}});`

pero cuando ejecuto esto me borra los demás objetos que están dentro de `modelable`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo agregar si que me borre los demás. Espero que me puedan ayudar gracias.

Comment: Hola, prueba usar tu sintaxis así **db.piloto.updateMany({}, { "$push": { "modelable": { "cargo": "" } } });** y nos comentas

Comment: Hola intente ejecutar el comando con el **$push** pero no me lo aplica

Comment: Da error o algo? puedes indicarnos que sucede al ejecutar?

Comment: el error es **Write operation error on server localhost:27017. Write error: WriteError{code=2, message='The field 'modelable' must be an array but is of type object in document {_id: ObjectId('645bb8bc5945cb83890dc9eb')}', details={}}.** me indica que no es un array, lo que tengo es un objeto dentro de otro objeto

Comment: Prueba a ver con esta opción para que no modifiques nada: **db.piloto.updateMany({}, { "$set": { "modelable.cargo": { "$ifNull": ["$modelable.cargo", ""] } } });**

Comment: me funciono muchas gracias te dejo la sintaxis como lo deje **db.piloto.updateMany({}, {"$set":{"modelable.cargo":null}})**

Comment: Dale, saludos y suerte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como tienes un objeto y para que no modifiques nada puedes usar:

```
db.piloto.updateMany({}, { "$set": { "modelable.cargo": { "$ifNull": ["$modelable.cargo", ""] } } });
```

Acá si ya existe deja el valor y en caso contrario hace una cadena vacia.

De esta forma no afectará al resto